# "Does not live long enough" error with `Weak<RefCell<_>>`

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I recently have many problems with the borrow checker of Rust refusing my code. In order to ask the question, I simplified my code:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

struct SomeOtherType<'a>{
    data: &'a i32,
}

struct MyType<'a> {
    some_data: i32,
    link_to_other_type: Weak<RefCell<SomeOtherType<'a>>>,
}

struct ParentStruct<'a> {
    some_other_other_data: i32,
    first_types: &'a Vec<MyType<'a>>,
}


fn get_parent_struct<'a>(first_types: &'a Vec<MyType<'a>>) -> ParentStruct<'a> {
    ParentStruct { some_other_other_data: 4, first_types: first_types }
} 

fn consume(parent_struct: ParentStruct) {
    print!("{}", parent_struct.first_types[0].some_data);
}

fn main() {
    let some_vect = vec!(
        MyType { some_data: 1, link_to_other_type: Weak::new() },
        MyType { some_data: 2, link_to_other_type: Weak::new() }
    );
    loop {
        let some_struct = get_parent_struct(&some_vect);
        consume(some_struct);
    }
}
```

This code doesn't compile, I have get following error:

```
error[E0597]: `some_vect` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:33:46
   |
33 |         let some_struct = get_parent_struct(&some_vect);
   |                                              ^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
36 | }
   | - `some_vect` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

But the strange fact is: if, in the type `MyType`, I change `Weak<RefCell<...>>` to `Rc<RefCell<...>>` or to `RefCell<...>` or to `Weak<...>`: it compiles!!

My question is: why? Why does the borrow checker refuses to compile the original code (and why does it accept the code with the other types instead of `Weak<RefCell<...>>`)?

Comment: For anyone interested in answering this question, I further [simplified the code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=68cdba0a208bbb4e3afbf63cdbf9ee7b&version=stable&mode=debug) (it still shows the same error) (@Truc Truca, if you want, you can edit your question and use the simplified code instead). So I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the invariance of `RefCell`. `Rc` and `Weak` also contain `Cell`s, maybe that's a hint? I need to stop researching this now, but I'm very curious to see a good explanation for this interesting question!

Comment: The solution is to use a different lifetime for the reference: `&'a Vec<MyType<'b>>` (maybe with `'b:'a`). As for the *why?* I'm not sure and will leave the answer to someone with a better understanding of lifetimes.

Comment: Also, very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210387/is-this-error-due-to-the-compilers-special-knowledge-about-refcell

Answer (score 3):

Since [Lukas Kalbertodt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2408867/lukas-kalbertodt) provided a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=68cdba0a208bbb4e3afbf63cdbf9ee7b&version=stable&mode=debug)), I'll use his code:

```
struct MyType<'a> {
    link_to_other_type: Weak<RefCell<&'a i32>>,
}

fn get_parent_struct<'a>(_: &'a MyType<'a>) {} 

fn main() {
    let foo = MyType { link_to_other_type: Weak::new() };
    get_parent_struct(&foo);
}
```

Let's go through it step by step:

- A `Weak` is created and moved into `MyType` with lifetime `'a`
- When it's passed to `get_parent_struct<'a>(_: &'a MyType<'a>)`, you have a reference with lifetime `'a` to a type with lifetime `'a`
- `get_parent_struct` expects it's parameter to live exactly as long as `foo` itself, which is not true, since `foo` lives until the end of the scope

As mentioned by [kazemakase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3005167/kazemakase), the solution is to use a different lifetime for the reference. If you alter the signature of `get_parent_struct` slightly, it's working:

```
fn get_parent_struct<'a>(_: &MyType<'a>) {}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cd14cb5f2de225a920ccb5162f8decca&version=stable&mode=debug)

The compiler will now elide the lifetimes to

```
fn get_parent_struct<'a, 'b>(_: &'b MyType<'a>) where 'a: 'b {}
```

Now `'a` outlives `'b`.