# Is `UnsafeCell` a compiler optimization barrier in Rust?

Tags: rust

In [Unsafe Code Guidelines Reference](https://rust-lang.github.io/unsafe-code-guidelines/glossary.html#interior-mutability), it says

> All interior mutation in Rust has to happen inside an `UnsafeCell`, so all data structures that have interior mutability must (directly or indirectly) use `UnsafeCell` for this purpose.

Also, in a [discussion about `UnsafeCell`](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/unsafecell-what-exactly-does-it-do-and-when-do-i-need-it/17471), it says

> `UnsafeCell` is basically an optimization barrier to the compiler.

It is true that `UnsafeCell` acts as a compiler optimization barrier in Rust? If yes, which line in the standard library source code emits a barrier and how does it work?

[UPDATE]

The [answer of a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210387/is-this-error-due-to-the-compilers-special-knowledge-about-refcell) gives a very nice explanation. The TL;DR version is: `UnsafeCell<T>` is marked with `#[lang = "unsafe_cell"]` which forces it to be invariant over `T`.

Now I think this is not very much connected to optimization, but interacts more closely with lifetime analysis.

For the notion of variance in Rust, [The Rustonomicon Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html) gives a detailed explanation.

Comment: @user4815162342 I would like to confirm my understanding. By applying `#[lang = "unsafe_cell"]`, it turns that `Wrapper<T>` is covariant over `T` into that `Wrapper<T>` is invariant over `T`. This is the so-called "barrier". Is it correct?

Comment: I'm not following you at all. My understanding is that `UnsafeCell` allows mutable aliasing to the data inside. The `lang = "unsafe_cell"` is the internal way how the standard library communicates to the compiler that it should disable the aliasing assumptions normally present. That is the "barrier" - the data is behind a barrier that prohibits normal optimizations based on aliasing rules.

Comment: It is true that `#[lang = "unsafe_cell"]` causes `UnsafeCell<T>` to be invariant over `T`, but it's not the invariance that inhibits optimization. Instead, it's because the `T` is mutable through a shared reference that certain optimizations are forbidden. Invariance is about making the type system aware of what you (the programmer) may do with the type; it doesn't relate to optimizations.